# Operations on Data Frame passed to function are very slow

Tags: r, dataframe, performance

In my example I have a 3D point cloud and want to find the outline for each z-layer.
My current approach is the following:

```
library(rgl) #just for 3D visualisation purposes of the cube

cube = data.frame(x = rep(1:10,1000),
                  y = rep(1:10, 100, each = 10),
                  z = rep(1:10,100,each = 100)) #3D point cloud

xyz_list = split(cube, cube[,3]) #split into layers by unique z-values

t0 = Sys.time()
outline = lapply(xyz_list, function(k){
  xmax = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum y-value for each unique x-value
  xmin = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum y-value for each unique x-value
  ymax = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum x-value for each unique y-value
  ymin = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum x-value for each unique y-value
  mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
  mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
})
t1 = Sys.time()
print(t1 - t0)

outline = do.call(rbind,outline)#merge lists
plot3d(cube)
plot3d(outline, col = "red", add = TRUE, size = 5)
```

Which takes approx. `0.33 secs`

Now I thought about passing the dataframe (`xyz_list`) to a function named `of` outside of `lapply` and move all the code from inside `lapply` to that function as I need to repeat the operations several times later on:

```
of = function(df, dim1, dim2){
  xmax = merge(aggregate(df[,dim1] ~ df[,dim2], FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  xmin = merge(aggregate(df[,dim1] ~ df[,dim2], FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  ymax = merge(aggregate(df[,dim2] ~ df[,dim1], FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  ymin = merge(aggregate(df[,dim2] ~ df[,dim1], FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
  mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
  return(mm)
}

t0 = Sys.time()
outline = lapply(xyz_list, function(k){
  mm = of(k, 2, 1)
})
t1 = Sys.time()
print(t1 - t0)
```

Which takes about `13 secs`.

I don't understand why my code has become so much slower in the second example. Is there some way to make the function `of` more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` solution:

I would recommend just subsetting on the larger `data.table` as needed instead of splitting it into separate `data.table`s by `z` layer. But if `outline` is really needed as a list of `data.table`s, we can split the `z` layers out after doing the summarizing:

```
library(data.table)

cube <- data.table(x = rep(1:10, 1000),
                   y = rep(1:10, 100, each = 10),
                   z = rep(1:10, 100, each = 100)) #3D point cloud

system.time({
  nms <- c("x", "y", "z")
  outline2 <- unique(rbindlist(lapply(1:2, function(i) setnames(cube[, .(range(.SD)), by = c(nms[-i]), .SDcols = nms[i]], "V1", nms[i])), use.names = TRUE))
  setcolorder(outline2, nms)
  outline2 <- split(outline2, outline2[[3]])
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.03    0.00    0.05
```

Compare to the original non-function solution:

```
system.time({
  xyz_list <- split(cube, cube[,3]) #split into layers by unique z-values
  
  outline1 <- lapply(xyz_list, function(k){
    xmax <- merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum y-value for each unique x-value
    xmin <- merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum y-value for each unique x-value
    ymax <- merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum x-value for each unique y-value
    ymin <- merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum x-value for each unique y-value
    mm <- rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
    mm <- mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
  })
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.64    0.01    0.66
```

If a function that operates on a list of pre-split layers is really needed:

```
of <- function(dt, dim1, dim2) {
  setcolorder(unique(rbindlist(lapply(c(dim1, dim2), function(i) setnames(dt[, .(range(.SD)), by = c(nms[-i]), .SDcols = nms[i]], "V1", nms[i])), use.names = TRUE)), nms)
}

system.time({
  outline3 <- lapply(xyz_list, function(k) of(k, 1, 2))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.06    0.00    0.06
```

We'll verify that the solutions all return the same set of values. In order to compare, we need to convert the `outline1` `data.frame`s to `data.table`s and reset their rownames. We also sort all the `data.table`s.

```
for (i in 1:length(outline1)) {
  setorder(setDT(outline1[[i]]))
  setorder(outline2[[i]])
  setorder(outline3[[i]])
  rownames(outline1[[i]]) <- NULL
}

identical(outline1, outline2)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(outline1, outline3)
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2022-01-31 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: the line with `outline2` slowly let my brain melt but after a while I got it. Thanks for suggesting data.table, it really made my code much faster actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
# dummy data
cube <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,1000),
                  y = rep(1:10, 100, each = 10),
                  z = rep(1:10,100,each = 100)
                  )

# split into list
xyz_list <- split(cube, cube[,3])
```

## op's original method (lapply only)

```
outline <- lapply(xyz_list, function(k)
  {
  xmax = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum y-value for each unique x-value
  xmin = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum y-value for each unique x-value
  ymax = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum x-value for each unique y-value
  ymin = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum x-value for each unique y-value
  mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
  mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
  })
```

## op's attempt to create function (then lapply)

```
of <- function(df, dim1, dim2)
  {
  xmax = merge(aggregate(df[,dim1] ~ df[,dim2], FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  xmin = merge(aggregate(df[,dim1] ~ df[,dim2], FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  ymax = merge(aggregate(df[,dim2] ~ df[,dim1], FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  ymin = merge(aggregate(df[,dim2] ~ df[,dim1], FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
  mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
  return(mm)
  }
```

## new, improved function

```
of1 <- function(df, y, x)
{
  y_x <- as.formula(paste(y, '~', x))
  x_y <- as.formula(paste(x, '~', y))
  xmax = merge(aggregate(y_x, FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  xmin = merge(aggregate(y_x, FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  ymax = merge(aggregate(x_y, FUN = max, data = df), df) 
  ymin = merge(aggregate(x_y, FUN = min, data = df), df) 
  mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
  mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
  return(mm)
}
```

## microbenchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

a <-
  microbenchmark(original = {outline = lapply(xyz_list, function(k)
                                        {
                                        xmax = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum y-value for each unique x-value
                                        xmin = merge(aggregate(y ~ x, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum y-value for each unique x-value
                                        ymax = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = max, data = k), k) #maximum x-value for each unique y-value
                                        ymin = merge(aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = min, data = k), k) #minimum x-value for each unique y-value
                                        mm = rbind(xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin) #collect all minimum and maximum values
                                        mm = mm[!duplicated(mm),] #remove duplicate rows
                                        })}
                 , slow = {outline1 = lapply( xyz_list, function(k) { of(k, 2, 1) } )}
                 , improved = {outline2 = lapply( xyz_list, function(k) of1(k, 'y', 'x') )}
                 , times = 30
                 )
autoplot(a)
```

[image: benchmark]

## identity check

```
identical(outline, outline2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for this very simple solution! :-)

Comment: @mri glad  could help